# Linear Permutations of $n$ objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose there are $n$ distinct objects $O_{1},O_{2},O_{3},\ldots,O_{n-1},O_{n}$. We have to find out the number of ways we can arrange them. But, there is a catch. We have to arrange them such that $O_{1}$ appears before $O_{2}$ and $O_{3}$. Also, $O_{3}$ must appear before $O_{4}$ and $O_{5}$ must appear before $O_{6}$. The rest can be arranged without any restrictions. Is there a general method to solving these type of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are several methods. The one I use is to put the restricted items $\{O_1,O_2,O_3,O_4,O_5,O_6\}$ to one side and find the permutations of the remainder, $(n-6)!$ . Then find the permitted permutations of $\{O_1,O_2,O_3,O_4\}$ - which is 3 - and note that the order of $\{O_5,O_6\}$ is fixed. Then insert the groups into the remainder of the permutation, choosing locatons using ${n+k\choose n}$ on  first $(n-6)$ and then $(n-2)$ pre-arranged items.

The answer then is 
$$\begin{align}
&(n-6)!\cdot 3 \cdot {n-2\choose 4}{n\choose 2} \\
&= 3(n-6)!\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-6)!4!}\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!} \\
&= \frac{3n!}{4!2!} \\
&= \frac{n!}{16}
\end{align}$$

(equivalent we can assemble the string to insert first; this is $(n-6)!\cdot 3\cdot {6\choose 2}{n\choose 6}$, giving the same result)